# Rest call doesn't retrieve subclass entities which exist

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm retrieving list of objects from database using JPA repository.
If I don't access sub classes in any way, they will be null.
If I just go and show count of them in log file, they will not be null.
I'm not sure why is this happening.

In below code, if I comment out 'for loop', policy.getFields() and policy.getFieldGroups will be null.
Why is this happening?

```
    log.debug("Request to get all Policies");
    List<Policy> policies = policyRepository.findAll();
    for (Policy policy : policies) {
        log.info("Policy fields group size:{}", policy.getFieldGroups().size());
        log.info("Policy fields size:{}", policy.getFields().size());
    }

    return policies;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called lazy loading (or lazy initialization) , which means that collection relations will be fetched when they are about to be used. This is perfectly normal behavior. If you need it everytime, you can change loading of that relation to EAGER so those will be fetched everytime.

This can be done by adding `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` on fields you are need to be loaded (here field groups and fields)